# How do I save the progress of my character in Warhammer 40,000: Carnage for iOS?

Tags: warhammer-40k-carnage

I bought **Warhammer 40,000: Carnage** for iOS some days ago.
The game itself is awesome, but I just can't find a way to save the progresses of my character.

Any time I close the application, all my progress is erased, and I'm forced to play all over again, right from the introduction.

Since the game has an RPG-like system, I assume there MUST be a way to save one's progress, but I just can't seem to find out how!

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Jason thanks for adding the appropriate tag, my reputation was too low to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in the same issue, and I have bad news for you, at least for now!
I contacted the guys at Roadhouse Games, and asked them about any available way to save the progress of my fellow space marine. This was their answer:

*Thank you for reaching out.*

*We have found a solution to this save issue, and are currently waiting on Apple to approve this fix and push it live. [...]*

*In the meantime, just hang tight. Your patience is greatly appreciated. [...]*

*Thanks again,*

I guess we just have to wait one or two weeks!

Comment: Hey! Praise you (and the Emperor, of course)!